# How can I join a list of Spark dataframes together in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `Seq` of Spark dataframes (i.e. `Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]`), it could contain 1 or many elements.
There is a list of columns that is common to each of those dataframes, each dataframe also has some additional columns. What I would like to do is join together all those dataframes using those common columns in the join conditions (remember, the number of dataframes is unknown)

How can I join together all these dataframes? I guess I could `foreach` over them but that doesn't seem very elegant. Can anyone come up with a more functional way of doing it? *edit: A recursive function would be better than a foreach, I'm working on that now, will post it up here when done*.

Here is some code that creates a list of n dataframes (n=3 in this case), each of which contains columns `id` & `Product`:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Feature Generator tests").config(conf).config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/tmp/hive").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
val df = spark.range(0, 1000).toDF().withColumn("Product", concat(lit("product"), col("id")))
val dataFrames = Seq(1,2,3).map(s => df.withColumn("_" + s.toString, lit(s)))
```

*To clarify, `dataFrames.head.columns` returns `Array[String] = Array(id, Product, _1)`.*

How might I join those n dataframes together on columns `id` & `Product` so that the returned dataframe has columns `Array[String] = Array(id, Product, _1, _2, _3)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dataFrames` is a `List`; You can use the `List.reduce` method to join all data frames inside:

```
dataFrames.reduce(_.join(_, Seq("id", "Product"))).show

//+---+---------+---+---+---+
//| id|  Product| _1| _2| _3|
//+---+---------+---+---+---+
//|  0| product0|  1|  2|  3|
//|  1| product1|  1|  2|  3|
//|  2| product2|  1|  2|  3|
//|  3| product3|  1|  2|  3|
//|  4| product4|  1|  2|  3|
//| ... more rows
```

Comment: this does'nt works when we have a huge list of data frames to join.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952740/joining-huge-list-of-data-frames-causes-stack-overflow-error